# How do I obtain the coordinates of the points that define the polygons' shape in ArcMap (not the centroid)?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, coordinates

I'm starting at ArcMap.

I want to export the coordinates of the points that form the line that defines the shape of each polygon.

I can add a new field to the attribute table, but when I calculate the geometry, it only provides coordinates of centroid, area and perimeter.

What about the "external" points I mentioned? How do I obtain them?

Comment: Each polygon is made of at least 4 points.  Coordinates of which one would you like to see in that polygon record?

Comment: The `Polygon` class is a superclass of `Geometry` and is itself an iterable (which returns a list of `Point`). Look at the documentation.

Comment: Or you could use the [Feature Vertices To Points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) then the [Add XY Coordinates](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm) tools

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look, see if I can obtain such information.

Comment: That's exactly it, @FelixIP. I'm still struggling in getting that information.

I was told that I should use ArcGIS API for python (I don't understand what's that for). But aparently that API requires ArcGIS Pro. Since I only have access to the ArcMap extension (it's a student's licence), I changed to QGIS so that I could use python console. I'm now studying pyQGIS documentation...

Comment: Look at help in arcgis, reading geometries. You'll find examples of extracting points coordinates using Python. All can be done with basic license.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @FelixIP, I'll do that!